# Communicating between swift and Python

Tags: python, ios, swift, objective-c, kivy

I am writing an IOS app with kivy (Python) , the only problem is that in-app-purchase can’t be done via stripe API. Only with Apples own API which as far as I know only works with swift and obj-c. I have 2 ideas : 1 write a small swift program and majd it communicate with the API then with the Python script. The second is to use obj-c inside the Python script. Does anyone has experience with such problem? Never used swift before but willing to go that way if it is easier. I want to stay with Python and kivy since i can compile to android and IOS aswell.

Any help would be nice.